# Irregularity in receiving Firebase notifications

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Sometimes even with a valid Firebase token, the notification is not sent to our users. Also often there is a delay when a notification is scheduled to all our users. In many cases this delay is more than 30 min. I have thoroughly checked our logs and there are no error responses when we send requests to FCM

Comment: this could only be because of network.

Comment: @PulkitKumarSingh The users who brought this to our attention had very good internet at the time they were supposed to receive the notification. Even in the least probable scenario that they didn't (which I find hard to believe), there is no reason for the notification to get lost without being delivered

Answer (score 2):

Firebase does not guarantee notification delivery. If you dig deep you will find many reported scenarios where this issue has been reported:

1. [Android: Delay in Receiving message in FCM(onMessageReceived)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725622/android-delay-in-receiving-message-in-fcmonmessagereceived)
2. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/83
3. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/83

Main scenarios could be:

- If the internet is not available.
- Differences in devices, how the code is written to handle notifications in different android versions.
- Background / foreground status.

Comment: The same device with solid network connection irrespective of foreground/background state sometimes receives notification within a second & sometimes with a delay & sometimes not at all. The issue that you have referred to seems to be the case of mine. Sadly it still remains unsolved.

Comment: Yes , I am also facing similar issue. Many more people also reported this issue. and surprisingly issue is closed by  firebase without resolving

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue tonight. Here's [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51380211/9304976) from similar question that i found.

From what I understood, the FCM attempts reconnecting the socket from device after intervals of 15 - 28 minuites depending on the network it is connected to. While doing so, it opens the app in background and fetches pending notifications if any.
It just so happens that sometimes it misses to fetch these pending notifications.

Conclusion - FCM is not very reliable[read 'sucks'] in timely delivery of our notifications.